# Mvc 5 ViewPage<T> becomes non generic ViewPage when compiled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm upgrading a site by creating a new ASP.Net Mvc 5 skeleton and then dropping in the content.
Currently all seems to be working except for the strongly typed views. All `Model` property access fails and it's evident that the nongeneric controller is used.

**Example:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MySite.Models.MyViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1><%= Model.Title %></h1>
</asp:Content>
```

I get the error *'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method...*

Going to Definition on Model takes me here:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the properties and methods that are needed to render a view as
    //     a Web Forms page.
    [FileLevelControlBuilder(typeof(ViewPageControlBuilder))]
    public class ViewPage : Page, IViewDataContainer
    {
        <snip>
        public object Model { get; }
```

How come it chooses the wrong item?

The project was created as a MVC4 project and then upgraded to MVC5 using nuget before any code was added.

Comment: According to the [source code and associated history](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewPage.cs), `object` has always been used. Did you follow the upgrade steps at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2? I don't know if the Nuget package will do all the web.config work for you.

Comment: @StevenV There's a generic version of that class too. I'll take a look at that doc, thanks!

Comment: I thought there was a generic version of the class, but I couldn't find it right away. Good luck!

Comment: @StevenV It was the manual config steps in both web configs, and the web-api registration that was missing. If you add it as a real answer and I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it doesn't appear that the Nuget packages for ASP.NET MVC 5 does not handle the needed web.config and code changes to support everything in ASP.NET MVC 5. Take a look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 which should help you do the needed manual upgrade steps that the Nuget package doesn't cover.

Answer (score 3):

For me I was missing this specficially in my `View/web.config` since the default config assumes razor.

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <pages pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, 
       Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, 
       Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
       userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, 
       Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
           >
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```